# Crash on touching two uitextview at a time

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitextview

I have two uitextviews in my application. Both objects are of same class of uitextview.I am passing notification with object self from touches begin method and touches ended from uitextview class for further processing of uitextview to another class. Now when i touch these two textviews simultaneously my app crashes with following error.

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

Comment: How did you find out where this was happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's means you insert a nil object to dictionary.
maybe objects[0].

Comment: This is my problem, but what does that really mean? Is my object deallocated? If that's the case, then I don't know how to do it.